# Session Flash Messages not showing anywhere despite coding

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I am following strict practices as per 5.2 docs, yet the validation is driving me insane.

1) This is a code snippet that I have in the controller right after the $property->save(); function

```
Session::flash('success', 'property table filled');
Session::flash('errors',  'These are the errors');
```

etc

Second issue is that the Validate method, if there are errors, it reverts back to the Create Form Page, but instead of binding the existing data in the Fields, it wipes everything out, so that I have to start the Form from scratch. Besides, it does not display any error messages

```
public function store(Request $request){            

             $this->validate($request, array(

            'country' => 'bail|required|max:100',
            'region'  => 'bail|required|max:100',
            etc
```

According to the documentation, this alone should, in case of fail to pass, revert back to the Create method above (the one that shows the Form to Create the Post) and issue a set of errors. 
Since I am using a Resource Controller, all of the Routes are included in one line, and also, all of the Controllers and stuff are inside the Web Middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>'web'], function(){
Route::auth();

  Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::resource('property', 'PropertyController');


});
```

This is the flawless snippet I have in the partials which is included in the Layout, so that it will display messages (success or fail) for every page that has a session:

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success" role="success">
<strong>Success: </strong>  {{Session::get('success')}}

</div>
@endif

<div class="row">
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

If instead, the storing of the data in the table database was successful, it still won't echo out any success flash session message.

Question:

Were there any errors in the submitted data, why doesn't display anything and why does it empty me all of the fields. The effect of emptying the fields is the same thing that would happen not when you refresh the Page, (filled fields stay filled) but when you click and press in the URL box of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is one of the cases where you get the answer but you dont know exactly why it works.

While I already had the Resource Controller Method inside the Web Middleware in the routes file, it turns out that I did not have to place the (or rather it was not enough) this:

```
Session::flash('success', 'property table filled');
Session::flash('errors',  'Posting failed');
```

in the Property Controller (and then this controller inside the Web Middleware in the Routes File), but actually those two lines on their own right in there in th Routes File

```
Session::flash('success', 'property table filled');
Session::flash('errors',  'Posting failed');
```

This is so much so that if I remove them from the Controller, this still works, but if I remove them from the Routes File, it doesn't.